# What does the keyword FUNCTION mean?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I found this query in the Spring project I am working :

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> getNombreOutilAffecteByEmploye(Flux flux, int top) {
    return getSession().createQuery("Select FUNCTION('concat',do.demandemoyen.employe.nom,' ',do.demandemoyen.employe.prenom),count(do.iddemandeoutil) as nbr from Demandeoutil do where do.demandemoyen.flux=:flux and do.retour=:retour group by do.demandemoyen.employe.nom,do.demandemoyen.employe.prenom order by nbr desc")
         .setParameter("retour",false)
         .setParameter("flux", flux)
         .setMaxResults(top)
         .getResultList();
    }
```

So why do they put the keyword FUNCTION ? What does it mean ?

Comment: There is probably a database function in your database with the name "function". Please check your database.

Comment: They did not give me yet the database script. So you think it is not a Postgres keyword ?

Comment: No, in PostgreSQL it's not a keyword: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: I got the database script, and there is no database object named `function` ! So what is it ?

Comment: Ask your colleges, they wrote this code.